# File operation on S3 file without download

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I want to know the File type using "file" command without downloading file from S3 in Nodejs.

so aim is to only hit the file , fire "File" command on it and retrieve it's output. How can I achieve this without downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the NodeJS S3 SDK to get the file details. There is a method that returns the object metadata. You can check the object `ContentType` to know its file type. It is returned in the response json when you make a request for an object's metadata.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property